# plotting numerous pie plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, bigdata, pie-chart

I am trying to plot 5625 (75*75), in ggplot2; It takes ages, and the quality of plot at the end is relatively low. Is there any other alternative, to plot such a thing?!

```
mydata = data.frame(side1=rep(colnames(cmap75),3,each=231),side2=rep(colnames(cmap75),231,each=3),widget=rep(colnames(cmap75),1),size=rep(1/3,231*3),strength=runif(3*231,-1,1))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x="",y = size, fill = strength, width = widget)) +
geom_bar(width = 1) + 
facet_grid(side1 ~ side2) +
scale_x_discrete("",breaks=NULL) + 
coord_polar("y") + scale_fill_gradient2() +
scale_y_continuous("",breaks=NULL)+ geom_point() +
theme(panel.grid=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank())+theme(panel.margin=unit(0,"mm"))
ggsave("ggplot1.pdf", width=20, height=20)
```

`colnames(cmap75)`, is just a vector of strings;
here is a smaller example

```
mydata = data.frame(side1=rep(LETTERS[1:6],3,each=18),side2=rep(LETTERS[1:6],18,each=3),widget=rep(LETTERS[1:6],1),size=rep(1/3,18*3),strength=runif(3*18,-1,1))
```

Comment: My first gut response would be that you are simply trying to plot too much data at once. Try and come up with ways to reduce your dataset (aggregation over a dimension, subsetting your data) to overcome this issue.

Comment: Furthermore the complaint about low quality cannot be replicated on my machine, at least if the "quality" is referring to low resolution. What machine are you on and what does `capabilities()` return? If the issue is just that the task won't fit on "one piece of paper" then how can we solve it other than suggesting an additional dimension of faceting. I do believe that faceting can have a page dimension as well as rows and columns.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Hiemstra well, I can't reduce the size, since, I thought it is a best way to illustrate 3 correlation matrix at once. each pie plot represents the similarity of two variable, and each piece is a different way calculating similarity.

Comment: @DWin I also think, I have to increase the page size, say 50cm * 50cm ...

Comment: Pie charts are generally not a good idea as they have major perceptual problems, see e.g. http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Pie-Charts-Are-Bad/.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra here, the size of pieces are not important at all, since all slices are equal to 33%.

Comment: As you are saying that the size of the pieces is not important, it is worth rethinking if you want to really use a pie chart. I can only second Hiemstra here - don't add visual features that don't add information. And rather use bar charts instead of pie charts, as comparing lengths is much easier than comparing pie piece size (or colour, as in your case). So I'd suggest to go from something like the following plotting code: `ggplot(mydata, aes(x=widget,y = strength)) + geom_bar(width = 1) + facet_grid(side1 ~ side2)`

Comment: If I do so, then I would have 75x75 barplot ! do you think, in such a plot one can really check the lengths ?!

Comment: Well, I would say that a comparison of the lengths of bars is at least easier to make by eye than a comparison of color shades. Also, if you would like to still add colors anyways, you can obviously also colour the bars with the `scale_fill_gradient2()` to add that level of distinction on top.